# ¿Porque Checkbox no ejecuta la función en dispositivo movil, aplicacion hibrida jquery?

Tags: jquery

Actualmente genero unos checkbox dinamicamente, pero el detalle que tengo es que al hacer pruebas en la computadora sobre esos checkbox, sin ningun problema ejecuta la función al seleccionar el checkbox, pero el problema sucede cuando genero el apk y lo ejecuto en el celular, en el celular no ejecuta la función pero si marca el checkbox:

De esta forma genero dinamicamente los checkbox con su informacion

```
 $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
                                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td td-cuponera-costarica')
                                            .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content').text(response.data[i].Nombre)))
                                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text(tipoCupon))
                                            .append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text("Descuento: "+response.data[i].Descuento)))
                                        .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
                                        .append('<div class="descuento_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Descuento + '</div>')
                                        .append('<div class="tipo_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Tipo_cupon + '</div>')
                                        .append('<div class="sub_tipo" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Sub_Tipo + '</div>')
                                        .append('<div class="vencimiento" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Fecha_vence + '</div>')

                                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                                    .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                                .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
                                                                .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                        .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida);
```

y esta es la funcion:

```
$('.cupones_bienvenida').on('click','.cupon_check', function(e){
console.log("Funcion ejecutada");
 });
```

Visualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la clase `.cupones_bienvenida` no existe en tu codigo cupones_bienvenida es una variable en tu codigo.

si pruebas asi

`$('.cupon_check').on('click', function(e){
console.log("Funcion ejecutada");
 });`